# junit test for stateless ejb + jpa

Tags: java, maven, jpa, junit4

I would like to write a junit test for my stateless ejb + jpa demo code. I think it is actually not a junit test, it is an integration test.

I have a stateless ejb with an injected EntityManager and PostgreSQL database server is used. I use CDI (Spring is not used in my project) and EclipseLink with a persistent.xml file. My application will be executed on GlassFish server.

I would like to write a test which checks the full logic: calls a method on my example stateless ejb and persist data into a in-memory database. I want to start the in-memory database with my tests and stop it when my test class was executed.

ejb class:

```
@Stateless
public class PropertyServiceImpl implements PropertyService {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "anything-jndi-em")
    private EntityManager em;

    public String getStringValue(final String key) {
        Property property = em.createNamedQuery("Property.findByKey", Property.class)
                .setParameter("key", key)
                .getSingleResult();

        return property.getValue();
    }
}
```

enitity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICATION_SETTING")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Property.findByKey", query = "select a from Property a where a.key = :key and a.status = 1")
})
public class Property
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "APPLICATION_SETTING_SEQ", sequenceName = "APPLICATION_SETTING_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "APPLICATION_SETTING_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "KEY", length = 200, nullable = false)
    private String key;
    ...
}
```

If I am correct I need to follow the next steps:

1. create a new persistent.xml file with the proper jdbc connection parameters which will connect to the in-memory dadabase and put it under the /test/Resources/META-INF folder
2. add some pom dependencies for in-memory database (ex.: hsqldb) and embedded ejb container
3. create a simple PropertyServiceImplTest.java class
4. configure somehow that the /test/Resources/META-INF/persistent.xml file will be user by my test class
5. initialize the embedded ejb container and start the in-memory database
6. execute my juni test method:

`@Test
    public void testGetStringValue() {
        PropertyService service = new PropertyServiceImpl();
        assertNotNull(service.getStringValue("abc"));
    }`

Could you please help my to write a proper test java class for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actual test case boot up the `javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer`. After that use its `javax.naming.Context` to lookup your stateless bean. The you can use your bean like you are used to and assert its behavior. Keep in mind that an embeddable container impl only has to support a subset (ejb lite) of functionality compared to a full blown ejb container. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/embeddedContainerDemo/EmbeddedContainerDemo.html#t2s5) you find a pretty neat example.

Code snippet:

```
JBContainer ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
Context ctx = ejbContainer.getContext();
PropertyService  service = (PropertyService) ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/PropertyServiceImpl");
assertNotNull(service.getStringValue("abc"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/). I use it with gradle on Wildfly 8, 9 and 10. Once setup properly, which can be a bit arduous, it works wonders.

You need only annotate your JUnit test like so:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MRSInjectionServiceTests extends ...
```

And then provide a deployment archive which I do via JBoss ShrinkWrap:

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(ZipImporter.class, "MRSInjectionServiceTests.war").importFrom(new File(ROOT_WAR_DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION)).as(WebArchive.class);
}
```

Then you can run these integration tests from maven or gradle. Arquillian will run your App server container (Wildfly, GLassfish, etcetera) based upon your configuration and will run the JUnit tests as a system test with your entire system running.

It is very nice. Well worth the effort.

Comment: I checked Arquillian and it looks interesting. Thx!

Comment: @sagneta, can you please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016391/null-object-when-testing-ejb-with-arquillian-in-eclipse)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I want to share with you my solution. According to your help I had a look at the Arquillian documentation and finally I was able to create a proper integration test.
My test uses GlassFish embedded EE container with HSQL in-memory database.

test java class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class PropertyServiceImplTest {

    @EJB
    private PropertyService propertyService;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar").
                .addPackage(Property.class.getPackage())
                .addPackage(PropertyService.class.getPackage())
                //.addPackage(PropertyServiceImpl.class.getPackage())
                addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetStringValue() {
        assertNotNull(propertyService);

        Property property = new Property();
        property.setKey("aaa");
        property.setValue("5");
        propertyService.setStringValue(property);

        assertEquals(propertyService.getStringValue("aaa"), "5");
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

- Valid values for target-database: [eclipselink doc](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm)

  ```
  <persistence-unit name="example" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jta-data-source>jdbc/my-ds</jta-data-source>
      <class>a.b.domain.Property</class>
      <properties>
          <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="HSQL"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  ```

**arquillian.xml**

How to eliminate the crazy "Potential problem found" warning message? DatatypeFactory properties has to be set.

```
WARNING: Potential problem found: The configured data type factory
         'class org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DefaultDataTypeFactory' might cause problems with the current database
           'HSQL Database Engine' (e.g. some datatypes may not be supported properly). In rare cases you might see this
           message because the list of supported database products is incomplete (list=[derby]). If so please request a
           java-class update via the forums.If you are using your own IDataTypeFactory extending DefaultDataTypeFactory,
           ensure that you override getValidDbProducts() to specify the supported database products.
```

- DBUnit specific settings: [jboss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Persistence)
- DataType factories: [dbunit documentation](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/properties.html#typefactory)

  ```
  <engine>
      <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/arquillian</property>
  </engine>

  <container default="true" qualifier="glassfish">
      <configuration>
          <property name="resourcesXml">myproject/src/test/resources/glassfish-resources.xml</property>
      </configuration>
  </container>

  <extension qualifier="persistence">
      <property name="defaultDataSource">jdbc/my-ds</property>
  </extension>

  <extension qualifier="persistence-dbunit">
      <property name="datatypeFactory">org.dbunit.ext.hsqldb.HsqldbDataTypeFactory</property>
  </extension>
  ```

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="jdbc/my-pool"
                          res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                          datasource-classname="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource">
        <property name="PortNumber" value="9001" />
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost" />
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:arquillian" />
        <property name="user" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </jdbc-connection-pool>

    <jdbc-resource jndi-name="jdbc/my-ds" pool-name="jdbc/my-pool" />
</resources>
```

**Project structure:**

- src/test/java/a.b.PropertyServiceImplTest.java
- src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
- src/test/resources/arquillian.xml
- src/test/resources/glassfish-resources.xml

Answer (score 0):

I am so disappointed after I spent 3-4 days with arquillian.

I read documentation about this testing framework and I have created a nice environment with it. There were created beautiful xml files with placeholders for prod and test environments and pom files are done. Everything works fine with my simple ejb and entity java classes.

Today I have been started working on my real java 8 application. After a while something had happened because my tests have failed. When I removed lambda expression from my code then my tests worked fine again.

So when I use lambda expression then the injected ejb is always null:
@EJB
private ConfigurationService configurationService;

The last release of GlassFish Managed 3.1 Container is 1.0.0.CR4, release date: 2013-04-29. It is quite old :(

Arquillian GlassFish module is totally useless :(

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too, but you can fix it using Payara's embedded server.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.162</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```