# Null object when testing EJB with Arquillian in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to test in Eclipse an EJB with Arquillian. I'm running this on Wildfly 20 with JDK 11 on Eclipse 2020 12 for Windows.

This is the bean:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class MyBean {

    public int add1(int x) {
            return x + 1;
    }
    
}
```

and this is the test:

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.core.api.annotation.Inject;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SqlQueryBeanTest {
    
    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap
                .create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClasses(MyBean.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    
    @Inject
    private MyBean bean;

    @Test
    public void readManyTest() {
        int x = bean.add1(2);
        Assert.assertEquals(x, 3);
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I run the test the `bean` object is null. How to fix this?

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>visualbank-ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>visualbank-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version> 
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-MR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.svenkubiak</groupId>
            <artifactId>jBCrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- START Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END Logging dependencies -->
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>azure-storage-file-share</artifactId>
          <version>12.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- START testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise.concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.enterprise.concurrent-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- END testing dependencies -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HTTP client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- formula calculation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jexl3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- BankLoad uses guava BiMap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Utilized by several app modules to send emails -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Reads files in CSV format -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>ejbModule</sourceDirectory>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>ejbModule</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>visualbank-common-2.0.jar</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>lib/jooq-3.11.10.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm also getting a warning, I'm not sure if it's related or not:

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING:
> Illegal reflective access by org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile$1
> (file:/C:/Users/pgsch/.m2/repository/org/jboss/classfilewriter/jboss-classfilewriter/1.1.2.Final/jboss-classfilewriter-1.1.2.Final.jar)
> to method
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
> org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile$1 WARNING: Use
> --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
> denied in a future release

After the UPDATE

[image]

Comment: You are targeting Java 8, but you run your application with a higher Java version, but lower than Java 17, hence the warning. Your code, or more likely some of your dependencies, are not ready for Java 17. Does updating the dependencies solve it?

Comment: I'm using Java 11, why you are saying that I'm targeting Java 8? how do I change that? I changed the maven-compiler-plugin to 1.11 but still have the error, what else I need to change?

Comment: For Java 11 set the `maven-compiler-plugin` to `11`, not to `1.11`. When you run it with Java 11, you'll get the warning which you wouldn't get with Java 8. I guess that it is not possible to run it with Java 17 without adaptations. Maybe updating the dependencies is enough to get rid of the warning with Java 11 and to make it work with Java 17.

Comment: This doesn't work even updating maven-compiler-plugin to 11. I cannot change the jdk and I'm running this on Wildfly 20 and I cannot change that either. Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, I was only talking about the warning which is not related to your main problem that the `bean` object is `null` (for which I don't know the answer).

Comment: Why that old Eclipse version? Are you 100% sure that none of the dependencies are Java 16 or higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pom.xml I've tryied with this and the test works

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>visualbank-ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>visualbank-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-MR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.svenkubiak</groupId>
            <artifactId>jBCrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- START Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-file-share</artifactId>
            <version>12.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- START testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise.concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.enterprise.concurrent-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.2020.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HTTP client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- formula calculation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jexl3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- BankLoad uses guava BiMap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Utilized by several app modules to send emails -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Reads files in CSV format -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>ejbModule</sourceDirectory>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>ejbModule</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>visualbank-common-2.0.jar</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>lib/jooq-3.11.10.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: After upgrading to Eclipse 2022 06 and JDK 17, I still have the problem that Maven classes cannot be `resolved as a type`

Comment: Which maven are you using? mvn clean package what error gives?

Comment: I managed to add explicitly the dependencies in pom.xml and compiled the project. But when I run the test I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error instantiating class org.hibernate.validator.cdi.ValidationExtension at org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.mock.ServiceLoader.prepareInstance(ServiceLoader.java:306)`

Comment: try to upgrade payara-embedded-all to version 5.2022.2 I see that org.hibernate.validator.cdi.ValidationExtension comes from that jar

Comment: That helped, but now I'm getting this: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Service class org.hibernate.validator.cdi.ValidationExtension didn't implement the Extension interface
 at org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.mock.ServiceLoader.loadClass(ServiceLoader.java:285)`

Comment: try to update arquillian-bom in dependecy management to 1.7.0.Alpha10, this should update arquillian-container-test-api. I'm not able to find `org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.mock.ServiceLoader` in any jar (that should be in `arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1` but no one depends on it, just run `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.jboss.arquillian.container`)

Comment: I had removed `arquillian-bom` from the pom, that's when things started working, I added manually `arquillian-container-test-api`, now the error is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/weld/validation/spi/ValidationServices
 at org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.mock.AbstractDeployment.configureServices(AbstractDeployment.java:70)`

Comment: do you still have weld-core in the pom?

Comment: yes, version 2.4.8.Final

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246825/discussion-between-pp88-and-ps0604).

Answer (score 0):

You are using Arquillian's `org.jboss.arquillian.core.api.annotation.Inject` annotation. According to its [JavaDoc](https://javadoc.io/static/org.jboss.arquillian.core/arquillian-core-api/1.5.0.Final/org/jboss/arquillian/core/api/annotation/Inject.html), it can only be defined on fields with specific types.

I'm not an Arquillian expert and you haven't really described, what you want to achieve with your code. But if you simply want to make use of the container's dependency injection, you have to use `javax.inject.Inject` instead. If this should be your intention, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50080294/13510562) would be a duplicate of your question.

Comment: Thanks, I tried many things, including `javax.inject.Inject` but always have the same problem: the bean is null.